# When does it make sense to use a public field?

Tags: c#, java, oop, design-patterns

This is a question I have had for a while now:

When does it make sense to expose a field publicly like so?

```
public class SomeClass()
{
   public int backing;
}
```

The downside of doing this (in addition to angering OOP elitists) is that you have to introduce a breaking change to your API if you ever need to add any logic on top of this data. I suppose that is what the elitists are on about.

Best practice in Java and C# has long been to use getters/setters or properties to access fields.

```
public class SomeClass()
{
   private int backing;

   public int getBacking()
   {
      return backing;
   }

   public void setBacking(int v)
   {
      backing = v;
   }
}
```

C# has evolved this to pretty simple syntax with automatic properties:

```
public class SomeClass()
{
   public int Backing { get; set; }
}
```

Lazy me still feels this is too long though since it something I find myself doing a lot. More importantly, I am not sure I know where a public field would make more sense.

Why not just treat publicly declared fields as properties (or methods) behind the scenes? That way it would be impossible to anger decoupling gods and be a bit less typing to boot.

```
public class SomeClass()
{
   public int backing;   // The same as public int backing { get; set; }
}
```

For a property that does nothing but wrap the underlying field, I am pretty sure the JIT optimizes the method calls away so performance is probably not the issue. Any thoughts? (other than the proper case convention for the field name)

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the responses. I feel like perhaps not everyone is understanding my question though. When would a public field be a better choice than a property? Why is it a better choice? If the only reason is convenience (less typing and clutter), then what would be the downside of having the compiler generate a property "under-the-hood" whenever a public field is encountered. Basically, it would be impossible to create a true public field (because they would all be properties). What would be wrong with that? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to type the whole property declaration you can use the property snippet ("prop")

Comment: If you are using visual studio, put your cursor where you want the property and type "prop" and then press TAB twice. A property template will be generated and the type will be highlighted. Enter the type of the property and press tab. Enter the name of the property and press enter. Done! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7d3wz0k(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 12):

In my opinion, when you design a structure of a class you should pay more attention to future changes and should always be friendly to them. If a future requirement need you to do some logic before returning a value instead of just returnning the value of the field, you'll have to change the interface of the class, and all users of your library will have to change. That usually become a disaster.

Keep in mind, the [open / close principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: My point exactly. What I am proposing is that the interface not change later. Even if you type what looks like a simple public field, the compiler could treat it like a property under the hood. Then later, when you realize you need a property, the interface does not need to change.

Comment: It worth noting this argument assumes your code is called by code you do not control, i.e. you are writing a library. Otherwise, turning a field into a property is a simple as choosing Refactor -> Encapsulate Field in your IDE.

Answer (score 6):

When does it make sense to expose a field publicly?

Among other places, on private classes as below.

```
public class MyOuterClass
{
      private class MyInnerClass
      {
            public int val ; // why bother w/boiler plate
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My question though is why doesn't the compiler generate the boiler-plate for me? I want to write exactly what you did but have the future flexibility of a property too. Before I go off an build a broken vanity language, I was hoping to understand the downside.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the summary of pros and cons of public fields:

**Advantages**

- Less clutter in the code
- Better performance (in some cases)

**Disadvantages**

- Representation can't be changed without changing the API
- Invariants can't be enforced (*unless* the field is immutable)
- No additional actions can be taken when accessing these fields

So when should we use public fields? Depends. It is obvious that for public classes disadvantages outweigh the advantages. Possible problems with evolving the code inside the package are far worse than more clutter in the code and minor performance impact.

However, a class can be package private or even private nested, in which case the probable changes to the code will be localized. Therefore it is absolutely possible to use public fields. Also there are cases when performance difference is not so little. For instance, Android Developers guide claims that it is a good practice to use [direct field access instead of getters/setters](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#internal_get_set) where it is possible because it is several times faster.

To sum up, I will quote one of my favourite books, Effective Java by J. Bloch, Item 14:

> In summary, public classes should never expose mutable fields. It is less harmful, though still questionable, for public classes to expose immutable fields. It is, however, sometimes desirable for package-private or private nested classes to expose fields, whether mutable or immutable.

Comment: Do you have any source of "better performance"? I always though properties without any logic (or even with a small amount of it) would be inlined.

Comment: @aero The link is right in the answer, where I mention Android Developer's Guide. I agree that in modern VMs the difference is most likely to be negligible. However, Google claims that on Android the difference is 3x without JIT and even 7x with JIT on Android 2.2. Therefore there is at least this case when you have to think about performance.

Comment: @Malcolm - Very interesting that Dalvik does not inline the calls in this case. At the very least, this warns against making too many assumptions about what the VM may or may not do. This reminds me of some of the Scala cross-talk about how the server JVM behaves vs. the client. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

One of the scenarios when public field is a better choice is providing constants of your class.

For example, see:

```
public const double PI
```

defined in System.Math.

This approach is favored because it explicitly informs consumers of your class, that this member does not include any logic, validation or any other state-related operation, thus can be used in whatever context you want.

The other one I can think of, is when you need classes as containers for simple operations (or just for passing the large number of params to a method), as an example see `System.Windows.Point`. In most cases, these containers are modeled as structs though.

Comment: "it explicitly informs consumers of your class, that this member does not include any logic, validation or any other state-related operation," This is an important concept for me. For this reason I very often use public readonly fields. While not exactly the same as constants in most cases it is. For some reason fxcop keeps whining about this suggesting properties instead though :/.

Comment: Yes, this is a good one. I agree that 'const' or 'readonly' fields should not be treated as properties.

Answer (score 4):

I think it makes sense when you want to group some variables/objects (kind of like a C `struct`). For example:

```
class Pixel {
  public int x;
  public int y;
  Color c;
  // Other Pixel related information
}
```

As there are no methods, nothing breaks if a wrong value is used and it nicely puts these variables together.

Comment: Nothing breaks until one day you decide that x and y both have to be positive, or you try to incorporate color-matching or other transformations on 'c' as an implementation detail. :-) I agree though that the day will never come for a lot of the code we write. I was hoping for something with the visual simplicity and appeal of your example with the flexibility of properties built-in.

Comment: If you decide to change the 'rules' of the data, of course you need to update (parts of) the rest of your application as well, with or without using public fields.

Comment: I do not think so. If 'x' in your example was already a property under the hood, then extending it later with explicit get/set methods would not change the interface. 'x' would still just be a property. So, that is the advantage as I see it. What is the downside though? I may be missing something.

Comment: @Justin: If a method which accepts a `Pixel` requires that x and y must be positive, then either that method must validate them, or it must use a *different data type* for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

So the best answer I can give is that when you do magic via reflection, as one is wont to do when taking advantage of a statically typed language, properties have meaning over fields. From things like ORM tools, to mappers, and to binding data, properties can have different meaning than fields from that behavioral standpoint.

The JITter doesn't turn properties into fields, it can inline them, though I won't promise it does in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

On projects with non-trivial complexity it is rarely - but sometimes - a good idea to use public fields. One example that comes to mind:

```
/** 
 * A two-dimensional mathematical vector. Immutable so instances may be freely shared
 * without violating encapsulation.
 */
public class Vec2 {
    public final int x, y;

    // bunch of constructors and methods omitted
}
```

Rationale: It is exceedingly unlikely that the internal representation will need to be changed, or any kind of operation be performed when reading `x` or `y`. That is, using a setter confers no benefit here.

However it would confer some costs:

1. The public final field will make it abundantly clear the class is immutable, with a getter, you have to trust the documentation comment. (Do note that the absence of a setter does not imply immutability, because some other method might assign the field)
2. Code accessing the vector would be slightly less readable, as get() confers no meaningful semantic information, but still has to be skipped over when reading the code (at least in Java, C# is better here).
3. This being an extremely low level class frequent use is possible, and invocation overhead might become an issue. Yes, the virtual machine can perform inlining in many cases, but at least for non-final methods, some overhead is likely to remain even if no subclasses are currently loaded.

Comment: As I see it, a type with public fields advertises that its purpose is to stick a few values together with duct tape.  Such types aren't "oopish", but if one needs to stick a few values together with duct tape, it's better to define a type which does that than one which tries to "act like an object".  Classes with exposed immutable fields, classes with exposed mutable fields, and (in .NET) structures with exposed mutable fields all have useful semantics in their own rights (mutable exposed-field classes are rare, but can be appropriate, especially in Java, in cases where...

Comment: ...many consecutive calls to a method will need to return multiple values to the caller.  Having a caller pass a mutable object to the called method which can store the desired values into it can often avoid the need to allocate a new object for every call).

Answer (score 1):

One scenario, at least in .NET, is interop with C APIs.  You'll often declare C# or VB versions of Windows API structs, and it's common to use public fields for these because the normal reason for making fields private -- to prevent someone messing with them behind your back -- breaks down.  In this case, you *know* that something is going to be changing the fields behind your back -- that's the whole purpose of having the struct!

Of course you typically won't expose those unencapsulated structs to application code -- you'll treat them as private elements of the P/Invoke module, so application code still won't be dealing with the public fields.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason for making the fields public in this case or is it just convention? When I have done similar things I was writing to private fields mostly.

Comment: Functionally, there's no reason to make the fields private or public: Win32 sees only the in-memory layout, and the visibility doesn't affect that.  So I guess it is just convention.  There's no encapsulation benefit to making the fields private, and loading the struct down with wrapper properties de-emphasises its 'plain C-style struct' nature and makes it look like a real business object.  Or maybe that's just my eyes **grin**.

Answer (score 1):

> Best practice in Java and C# has long been to use getters/setters or properties to access fields.

I think that is the first problem: the idea that if you have a getter you must also have a setter. This is a mistake; in many cases a setter is unecessary because there is no real need to modify the attribute value of an object, and removing the possibility simplifies the class.

The extreme cases is to have no mutators at all. The final stage to making the class *immutable* is never to make mutable field values (remember, Java `final` is not like C++ `const`) directly accessible. And small value classes should be immutable. Only a getter method can provide safe access to potentially mutable fields, by creating a copy (in C++ you simply have a getter that returns by value). You *could* dispense with the getter for those fields that do not require defensive copying, but then some fields in a class might require a getter and some not. But that would be confusing,

Comment: Thanks. This is great thinking. A public field has the same issue of course so making it a property (compiler generated getter/setter) does not make anything worse. Also, I am not suggesting taking away the ability to manually create getter/setter code that works with a 'private' field. So, unless I am missing something, this would not be a reason to keep public fields as a language feature (as opposed to properties that look like public fields syntax-wise).

Answer (score 0):

You can use, in java, a public field, and then add some logic to it, like if there was a getter, using AspectJ, there including avoid writing to it if not from a specific psckage etc...

While this is a major improvement, that speeds up coding and still leaves a lot of space for future improvements without having everyone to rewrite all their code, it is not used that much, cause elitists are notoriously bigots.

Back to your question, since jit there is not great improvement in using public fields as opposed to getters/setters, and since IDEs have automatic getters and setters generation there is no real programmer overhead in using getters and setters. In years of Java programming I've used public fields only a couple of times, and always ended up converting them to getters/setters pairs.

Comment: I am not really familiar with AspectJ but you are talking about injecting bytecode at run-time correct? That is really something else entirely. Thanks.

Comment: yes, it is about injecting bytecode. while this sound scary to most, any ORM out there is doing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Among all the other answers, there are some situations where you have to use public fields in public classes. Using Unity 3D for instance. The serializer only serializes the fields and not the properties (for better performance). So before implementing your class, research on how the libraries and the frameworks you're using work. They might need some of your fields to be public in order to work as expected.

Comment: In the time the answer was written, Unity already had plenty of support for serializing private fields with `[SerializeField]`. It can even serialize the field of an auto-property with `[field: SerializeField]`. So you can have a private field and expose for the code the property, or you can have an auto-property (even with private setter) instead of a public field.

Comment: Please note that the question "When does it make sense to use a public field?" is not asking whether it's possible to not to use public fields. I didn't indicate Unity does not support private filed and property backing field serialization. I just pointed out a scenario where you'd use a public field (without decoration and additional code) and it also seems to have performance related reasons for game projects.